# Animation on keyframe and timeline

Tags: animation, nla-editor

1. How do you loop an animation inserted between, for example, keyframe 1 and 20, through out the whole 250 frames on the timeline?
2. How do you animate a torus on repeat?

Answer (score 2):

When you add keyframes they are stored in an [*Action*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet/Action) to let them repeat add the action as an *Action Strip* to the [*NLA Editor*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/NLA) and set the repeat property (in the property panel <kbd>N</kbd>) to the number of repetitions. Note that the *Action Editor* is mode of the [*Dopesheet Editor*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet).

[image]

Comment: Where can I view the repeat property? Sorry I am very new to Blender. I am using Blender 2.71.

Comment: Nevermind. I have found the repeat property. Thank you for your help.